# AWS batch job submit error-Batch.ClientException

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am following the hands-on tutorials on combining step functions with batch. Everything goes well until I start execution. After I start the execution of the state machine, I get the error of "Batch.ClientException".
The full error message is: `{
  "error": "Batch.ClientException",
  "cause": "JobDefinition arn:aws:batch:US-EAST-1:276943496984:job-definition/StepsBatchTutorial_ExtractMetadata:1 not found. (Service: AWSBatch; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ClientException; Request ID: 86da3335-5e8d-469f-bb51-8fc78d000dce)"
}`

The only thing I did that is different from the tutorial is that the IAM role used for the execution is created automatically by the system with a different name from the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

When u submit a AWS Batch Job the ClientException (HTTP Status Code: 400) usually occurs at two cases:

1.When using an action or resource on behalf of a user that does not have permissions to use the action or the resource

2.Specifying an identifier that is not valid

I dont think there is an issue with the permissions, since the IAM role is automatically created by AWS. But as the error says

`JobDefinition arn:aws:batch:US-EAST-1:276943496984:job-definition/StepsBatchTutorial_ExtractMetadata:1 not found`

Please check if the Job definition given here is valid.

Comment: I have solved the problem. It is all about writting the correct the `JobDefinition` parameter. Check if the parameter value is the same as the those defined in the jobs created.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure the batch runs correctly, check if the `JobDefination` parameter is the same as the job names created. The versions of the jobs may be changed.